# Pandas Row-wise Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to perform a calculation using the data in a dataframe row.

I've set the DF up like this

```
stages = {'Blade Lengths':'','Blade Midspans':'', 'Blade Linear Velocity':'','Stage 
Loading':'','Annulus Areas':'','Flow Co-efficient':'','Stage Reactions':'', 
'Temperature':'', 'Alpha 1':'', 'Alpha 2':''}

pdf = pd.DataFrame(stages, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])

pdf.index.name = 'Stage'
```

What I want to do is perform a calculation using the values from the data frame and put them into a new column. I have read that I could use iterrows() for this but that it is bad coding practice and it should be done differently, but I'm not sure how to vectorise my code.

The calculation for lambda uses "Flow Co-efficient", "Alpha1" and "Alpha2" from the DF.

lambda = 1 - 0.5* flow co-efficient *(tan(alpha1)+tan(alpha2))

How do i vectorise this calculation into my code?

The output should be in a list format, which i then will add into the dataframe too.

heres an example for one row

Blade Lengths    Blade Midspan  Blade Linear Velocity    Stage Loading   Annulus Area   Flow Co-efficient    Stage Reactions     Temperature    Alpha 1 (deg)   Alpha 2 (deg)   Lambda
Stage
140 0.43    385 0.318566    0.567561    0.558518        300 [10,15,20]  [0.10757322987417763, 0.16346993498204695, 0.22205027001971922, 0.28448409143768066, 0.35222875691463784, 0.42718128652133747, 0.5119163111016614, 0.6100781028629801]

Comment: Can you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: I have added, thanks for your time reading my post

Comment: You should add it as text rather than as an image :)

Comment: Check out `np.vectorize()` and using `.apply()` with `axis=1`.

Comment: I have edited to add the text but it is not formatted well :( sorry! I couldnt find a good way to add table